# Origin of the word "vector"

Tags: mathematics, physics, terminology

I would like to know the history and the original meaning of the word "vector". Thank you for any hints.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector.

Comment: I'm putting this question on hold because it shows insufficient prior research. The *obvious* Wikipedia article (linked above) contains the information requested.

Answer (score 2):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* has this:

J. Harris *Lexicon Technicum I*, 1704

> A Line supposed to be drawn from any Planet moving round a Center, or the Focus of an Ellipsis, to that Center or Focus, is by some Writers of the New Astronomy, called the Vector; because 'tis that Line by which the Planet seems to be carried round its Center.

Comment: For the benefit of non-Latinists: "vector" means "carrier".